# ng-options from a json with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i got a json that looks like this

```
[{"partner_id":"8","partner_name":"Company1","partner_location":["Place1","Place2","Place3"],"partner_user":["User1","User2","User3"]},{"partner_id":"9","partner_name":"Company2","partner_location":["Place4","Place5"],"partner_user":["User4","User5"]}]
```

Now i want to do something like this. I have 2  dropdowns and i want the first one to be filled with the partner_name from my 2 lists so it has to look like this

```
<select>
    <option value="8">Company1</option>
    <option value="9">Company2</option>
</select>
```

but i want it to be selected already with a value that i set inside `service_id`.
I understand you can do this somehow like this

```
<select ng-options="partner for partner in jsonPartners" ng-model="service_id"></select>
```

but when i do this, i have inside my select 2 options called `[object Object]`

And the 2nd select is more tricky, i want it to have the locations of what the id was selected in my 1st select. So if i selected `Company1`, than it should be filled with `Place1, Place2, Place3` and if i selected `Company2`, it should be filled with `Place4, Place5`.

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: pls can you show me what containing jsonPartners ? You have two selects and you want to after first changed populate second right ?

Comment: try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XaC8e/1/)

Comment: yes, the jsonPartners is the json i wrote on the begining of my post

Comment: ok i found the solution to my first problem, it looks like this
<select ng-model="service_id" ng-options="partner.partner_id as partner.partner_name for partner in jsonPartners"></select>

Comment: @Pacuraru Daniel its for key = val in option like value = name text. Look at oficial documentation its good if you read that. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-options="partner as partner.partner_name 
    for partner in jsonPartners" ng-model="service_id"></select>

    <select ng-options="place for place in service_id.partner_location" 
    ng-model="service_location"></select>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.jsonPartners = [{"partner_id":"8", ..},{"partner_id":"9", ..}]

    $scope.service_id = $scope.jsonPartners[1];
}
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwbsT/25/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I would add the `ng-change` to select 1st item by default:

**JS controller**

```
$scope.jsonPartners = [{
    "partner_id": "8",
    "partner_name": "Company1",
    "partner_location": ["Place1", "Place2", "Place3"],
    "partner_user": ["User1", "User2", "User3"]
}, {
    "partner_id": "9",
    "partner_name": "Company2",
    "partner_location": ["Place4", "Place5"],
    "partner_user": ["User4", "User5"]
}];


$scope.partner = $scope.jsonPartners[0];
$scope.place = $scope.partner.partner_location[0];

$scope.onChange = function(partner){       
  $scope.place = partner.partner_location[0];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
     <select ng-model="partner"          
     ng-options="partner as partner.partner_name for partner in jsonPartners"
         ng-change="onChange(partner)"
     ></select>

     <select ng-model="place"         
             ng-options="place as place for place in partner.partner_location"         
      ></select>
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/741/)**</kbd>

Comment: thank you for the answer, i used the one CodeHater provided and it is exactly the same idea like yours, which is great! i finally figured it out how it works :)