# how make ng-options with json and dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Help me please, how make ng-options with json:

```
{"bmw"{"x3","x5"},"audi"{"a5","a7"}}
```

With dropdown(if it possible):

```
<option>bmw</option> ->onclick show all bmw
"<option>x3</option>
"<option>x5</option>
<option>audi</option> - onclick show all audi
"<option>a5</option>
"<option>a7</option>
```

onclick it must slidedown and showing cars of this brand, maybe it would be directive? Or it can be done with standart angular methods? And how make this grouping with json that i wrote?
Thanks.

Comment: [Potential duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950165/ng-options-from-a-json-with-angularjs) and here http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/741/

Comment: Like a "nested dropdown" with sub-options?

Comment: use optgroup for grouping

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/XcTscLtfyaYgbYr2TcT4?p=preview) @unrealisted